# What causes this error? The TargetControlID of <CheckBoxControlName> is not valid. The value cannot be null or empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have searched on the net for this error, but there doesn't appear to be alot on it.

```
The TargetControlID of 'CheckBoxControlName' is not valid. The value cannot be null or empty.
```

Does anyone know of the main causes for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to associate one control with an other, but the id that you give is not exist.

Comment: If it doesn't exist, how was it possible for the reference (or control id) to have been created in the first place?

Comment: @aspdotnetuser Maybe copy/paste of code ? or you remove it later ? - eg when I copy paste a Panel is usually associate with the default button, if I change the id, I need to change and the default button id.

Comment: The ID is created dynamically, it hasn't been deleted or moved.

Comment: @aspdotnetuser what control is that ?

Comment: It's a MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtender

Comment: @aspdotnetuser look this example http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/HOW%20TO%20Use%20the%20MutuallyExclusiveCheckBox%20Control.ashx  and I hope you understand what is done

Answer (score 1):

The main cause is that the TargetControlID is not valid, and that the value is null or empty.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the `TargetControlID` property of the check-box control in question is NULL or empty.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get the server error displayed, but it doesn't stop on the line of code when the exception occurrs so I can't see what's happening.